# JS - jQuery - Enable Disable form fields with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to disable an input Box AND a button when a checkbox is clicked .

My markup :

```
<h4>Random or Not </h4>

    <!-- Use Random Image -->  

    <label><input name="o99_aufu_options[o99_aufu_random]" id="o99_aufu_options[o99_aufu_random]" value="1" checked="checked" type="checkbox">Use Random Image ? <em></em></label><br>  

    <!-- If the above not checked - needs to be enabled -->                         
    Upload Image <label for="upload_image"> <input id="upload_image" size="36" name="o99_aufu_options[o99_aufu_upload_image]" value="" type="text"> <input id="upload_image_button" value="Choose Image or upload" type="button"> </label>
```

jQuery :

```
if (jQuery('#o99_aufu_options[o99_aufu_random]').is(':checked')) {
       jQuery('#upload_image :input').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        jQuery('#upload_image_button,#upload_image :input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
```

well - obviously, if i am asking here - it is not working :-)

Fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/6jFMf/3/

Also as a bonus question - is it possible to do that only with the NAME of the input, omitting the ID from the markup ?

**UPDATE I** - working solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/6jFMf/20/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > bonus question - is it possible to do that only with the NAME of the input, omitting the ID from the markup ?

You can use any attribute in a jQuery selector, including name:

```
$('[name="foo"])
```

Since your names have brackets, you'll probably have to escape them:

```
$('[name="o99_aufu_options\[o99_aufu_random\]"]')
```

You can also qualify them to specific elements if you want, or combine them with other selectors:

```
$('input.someClass[name="o99_aufu_options\[o99_aufu_random\]"]')
```

As for your actual question, my first guess ... is wrong <strike>is that your problem is whitespace; have you tried:</strike>

```
#upload_image:input
```

instead?

My second guess is also wrong <strike>that the problem is:</strike>

```
.prop('disabled', true);
```

Have you tried:

```
.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

?

Ok, I actually looked at your fiddle, and there were a few things wrong; here's a working example, let me know if you have questions, but hopefully it's self-explanatory:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('input[name="o99_aufu_options\[o99_aufu_random\]"]').click(function(){
        var isChecked = jQuery(this).is(':checked') ;
        jQuery('#upload_image:input').prop('disabled', isChecked? 'disabled' : null);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thaks for your answers , but trying on the fiddle - it  does not seem to work .

Comment: I've updated my answer; can you please review my latest suggestion?

Comment: Thanks - it works great . Only thing is that when the document is loading - the function did not controlled it . I added a "disabled" attribute as default (see here : http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/6jFMf/20/ ). BTW - you do know you can save the fiddle changes by clicking "update" and then post the new link here ?

Comment: shouldn't you use .prop for best code practice? $( elem ).prop( "checked" )

Comment: I'm not sure if `prop` even existed when I wrote this answer :-)  It probably did, but just hadn't become standard practice yet.  Either way, I'll update my answer.